# Fetch all variables from external php file

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, var-dump

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

Here is my code :

```
$myVars=file_get_contents('1.php');

highlight_string($myVars);

$ignore=array('GLOBALS', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET', '_SERVER', '_ENV');
$myVars=array_diff_key(get_defined_vars()+array_flip($ignore),array_flip($ignore));

exit;
```

I'm trying to fetch all variables (except php predefined variables) into an array.

Small tweak needed here :)

Comment: use include() and get your vars. file_get_contents() will give you contents

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must not only include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem and the desired behavior, but also a specific problem or error. So, please explain what's wrong with your code. In how far is the output different from the output you want?

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma I want to obfuscate the variables therefore I can't use include. I do not want to run the code just fetch all variables and obfuscate them.

Comment: @iprophesy Without an include i don't think you can do that, but with an include it's pretty easy

Comment: @iprophesy: This is helpful context. Next time please include context information into your question right from the start. Otherwise we might run into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @honk You are right :) I assumed that it would be easier...